# Native C++ UWP creating folders and files

Tags: c++, uwp

I have an already existing C++ library that creates a folder and some files in it given a relative path.

How can I port this to UWP preferably without changing the c++ library?

When I try to create the folder to `"${USER_HOME}AppData\Local\Packages\${APP_NAME}_phhqn29e7p872\LocalState\relative_path"`(which is the Local Data path) I get `Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.`

Comment: Could you tell me whether your c++ library is a static library or a dynamic library? Is your UWP project a C++/WinRT project or a C++/CX project?

Comment: It's a static library, C++WinRT

Comment: Please check if your Local Data path can be accessed in the UWP project to determine if the error is related to UWP.If the Local Data path can be accessed in your UWP project, you could refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-160#BK_StaticLib) to use a native C++ static library in a UWP app.
In addition, you could also try to port your C++ library to a C++/WinRT component which turns your C++ library into a DLL and you can use it in any C++ UWP app referring to the  above document.